# GPS Module blinking but not receiving any data with RPi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, gps, uart, gpsd

I am using a Neo-7M-0-000 GPS Module and the on-board LED is blinking, meaning it has a fix. But when I try to get the readings either through

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

or through

```
cgps -s
```

It says "NO FIX".

I have connected VCC to 3.3V, GND to GND, TX to RX and RX to TX on a Raspberry Pi 3B.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does `sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0` output exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point it to /dev/ttyS0 instead, AMA0 only on Pi 1 & 2.

Make sure serial is enabled

```
sudo raspi-config
```

P6 Interfacing Options

No to enabling login shell

Yes to enable serial port hardware

Then run

```
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyS0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Test with `cgps -s`